# How do I change a global variables contents within a function

Tags: python, variables

I have created the following sample program to demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

```
name = "d"

def namechange (name):

    global name
    name = "Henry"
    return name

print name
```

The errors that is produced:

```
SyntaxError: name 'name' is local and global
```

I understand that the name variable is local and global, but I am new to this and do not know how to resolve this issue. Please help

Comment: Remove `name` from the parameters of `namechange`. That is the local `name` variable Python is referring to.

Comment: Your function is accepting the argument `name`, making it a local.

Answer (score 1):

```
def namechange (name):
```

This introduces a *local* variable `name`.

```
global name
```

Yet this also introduces the *global* variable `name` in the same scope.

Hence the syntax error that `name` is both local and global. In order to fix this, you have to either remove the local variable, or the global variable. In your case, you could do both.

You could either remove the local variable and just make the function modify the global variable, like this:

```
def namechange ():
    global name
    name = "Henry"
```

In that case, you don’t actually need to return anything, since this already modifies the global variable.

Or you could remove the global variable, and make this function just return the new value:

```
def namechange (name):
    name = "Henry"
    return name
```

In that case, it would be the caller’s responsibility to update the variable from the outer scope:

```
name = "d"
new_name = namechange(name)
print(new_name) # Henry
```

Answer (score 1):

Python considers function parameters as local variable. So since your function is accepting a parameter also named `name`, Python now considers `name` to be a local variable:

```
>>> global_variable = 0
>>> def foo(global_variable): # your creating a local variable here.
    global global_variable

SyntaxError: name 'global_variable' is parameter and global
>>>
```

The fix is to remove name from your functions parameters. That way, Python will see `name` as a global variable:

```
name = "d"   

def namechange (): # remove name
    global name
    name = "Henry"

print name
```

However, you should avoid using globals when you can. In this case, it would be a better solution to pass name as a parameter to your function, and let the caller deal with updating the variable:

```
name = "d"   

def namechange (name):
    name = "Henry"
    return name

new_name = namechange(name)
print new_name
```